# How can you limit the amount of memory an application in Windows 7 x64 can use? In particular X3 Terran Conflict

Tags: windows-7, memory, paging

I am running the latest version of X3 Terran Conflict (3.1) and after about 30 min - 1 hour it's memory usage goes well above 2 GB.  I only have 4 GB of ram, running Windows 7 64 bit.  As a result of X3 using more ram than is available, my hard drive starts paging and makes the game and other applications become unusable.  I have to restart the game.

Is anyone aware of this issue or how to fix it and is there any way in Windows or through some tool, to limit how much memory is given to the game?

Is this a bug in the game? Can this even be fixed?  I'm using some mods but I doubt any of them are causing this as they are simple mods like adding a tractor beam etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a bug somewhere.  I'm not familiar with the game, but it's quite possible that the mods could be the source of the memory leak.  It would be a useful test to play with no mods and/or a limited set of mods to determine whether it's the base game or a particular mod that's at fault.

As a direct answer, no, I don't believe there is a way to constrain Windows' memory manager in the way you've asked.

Personally, I figure anything using more RAM than I have available deserves to get an out of memory error.   I have paging disabled on my system (albeit with 8gb rather than 4) to no ill effects to date.

If you want to follow suit:

- right-click My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings

  Settings button below the Performance heading

  Advanced tab at the top

  Change... button

  Uncheck 'Automatically manage'

  Select 'No paging file' and click 'Set' for each drive that has a paging file in the list

  'OK' your way out

  Agree to reboot

Now, if you ever actually need more memory than you physically have for whatever you're doing, your app(s) will blow up...  But what are the odds?  And if you do push your system that hard, wouldn't you rather get an error and go close something than slog through page file thrashing?

Answer (score 2):

If you limited the amount of memory it could use, it would probably crash when you hit the limit anyway.

Sounds like a memory leak though.

Comment: Yeah i was thinking it might be.  Have you heard anything about this particular problem for this game?  They added > 2GB memory support in a version, then removed it in a later version due to an issue, and in a later version they added it back again.

Comment: @Coder You can ask issues regarding the game on the [gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/) forum